# How to retrieve the page source through Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, web-crawler

I want to use selenium to get data from this website:

https://e-civic.coquitlam.ca/tempestprod/webinquiry/frames.cfm

When I use:

```
driver.get(url_main)

driver.page_source
```

It returns like that:

```
<!-- Vers: 80000 9 --><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>\n\t<title>The City of Coquitlam Property Inquiry System</title>\n</head>\n<frameset rows="100%, *" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">\n\t<frame src="default.cfm?autorefresh=yes" name="frame_map" id="frame_map" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" noresize="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" />\n\t<frame src="nothing.cfm" name="frame_action" id="frame_action" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" />\n</frameset>\n</html>
```

instead of full html of the page, how can I get the full page of this website?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code :

```
driver.get("https://e-civic.coquitlam.ca/tempestprod/webinquiry/frames.cfm")  
driver.switch_to.frame("frame_map")
print(driver.page_source)
```

Note that your page content is in **frame**. In order to interact with `element/elements` which are in **iframe/frame/frameset** , you will have to switch the focus of your **web driver** to the respective frame.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Using *Selenium* to extract data from the website `https://e-civic.coquitlam.ca/tempestprod/webinquiry/frames.cfm` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the intended *frame to be available and switch to it* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')    
  driver.get('https://e-civic.coquitlam.ca/tempestprod/webinquiry/frames.cfm')       
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"frame_map")))
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <!-- Vers: 80000 9 --><!-- Vers: 80000 9 --><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
      <title>The City of Coquitlam Property Inquiry System</title>
  </head>

  <body onload="window.location.replace('default.cfm');" topmargin="5" leftmargin="5" rightmargin="5" bottommargin="0" bgcolor="white" text="black" link="#0065A4" vlink="5C5C5C" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

  <form action="menuredirect.cfm" method="post" name="menuadminform">

  <input type="Hidden" name="goto" value="admin" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_sessionid" value="0769A2DA-5056-AE78-7AD8DE5CC457342D" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_userid" value="GUEST" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_layerid" value="WC001-20030620175710" />

  </form>

  <form action="menuredirect.cfm" method="post" name="menumapform">

  <input type="Hidden" name="goto" value="map" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_sessionid" value="0769A2DA-5056-AE78-7AD8DE5CC457342D" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_userid" value="GUEST" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_layerid" value="WC001-20030620175710" />

  </form>

  <form action="menuredirect.cfm" method="post" name="menuselectionlistform">

  <input type="Hidden" name="goto" value="selectionlist" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_sessionid" value="0769A2DA-5056-AE78-7AD8DE5CC457342D" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_userid" value="GUEST" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_layerid" value="WC001-20030620175710" />

  </form>

  <form action="menuredirect.cfm" method="post" name="menureportsform">

  <input type="Hidden" name="goto" value="reports" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_sessionid" value="0769A2DA-5056-AE78-7AD8DE5CC457342D" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_userid" value="GUEST" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_layerid" value="WC001-20030620175710" />

  </form>

  <form action="menuredirect.cfm" method="post" name="menuhomeform">

  <input type="Hidden" name="goto" value="default" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_sessionid" value="0769A2DA-5056-AE78-7AD8DE5CC457342D" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_userid" value="GUEST" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_layerid" value="WC001-20030620175710" />

  </form>

  <form target="_blank" action="menuredirect.cfm" method="post" name="menudisclaimerform">

  <input type="Hidden" name="goto" value="disclaimer" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_sessionid" value="0769A2DA-5056-AE78-7AD8DE5CC457342D" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_userid" value="GUEST" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_layerid" value="WC001-20030620175710" />

  </form>

  <form action="menuredirect.cfm" method="post" name="menulayerform">

  <input type="Hidden" name="goto" value="layers" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_sessionid" value="0769A2DA-5056-AE78-7AD8DE5CC457342D" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_userid" value="GUEST" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_layerid" value="WC001-20030620175710" />

  </form>

  <form action="menuredirect.cfm" method="post" name="menuloginform" target="tempestwiloginwindow">

  <input type="Hidden" name="goto" value="login" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_sessionid" value="0769A2DA-5056-AE78-7AD8DE5CC457342D" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_userid" value="GUEST" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_layerid" value="WC001-20030620175710" />

  </form>

  <form action="menuredirect.cfm" method="post" name="menulogoutform">

  <input type="Hidden" name="goto" value="logout" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_sessionid" value="0769A2DA-5056-AE78-7AD8DE5CC457342D" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_userid" value="GUEST" />
  <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_layerid" value="WC001-20030620175710" />

  <input type="Hidden" name="logoutmessage" value="You have been logged out." />

  </form>



  <font face="Arial">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

      <tbody><tr><td>

  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bordercolor="Black">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td align="Left">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bordercolor="Black" width="100%">
          <tbody><tr>



              <td background="/tempestprod/webinquiry/inhouse/coquitlam_header_background.gif" width="100%" align="LEFT">
                  <a href="http://www.coquitlam.ca" target="new">
                      <img ismap="" usemap="#map" src="inhouse/coquitlam_logo_white.png" border="0" alt="coquitlam.ca" />
                  </a>
              </td>




          </tr>
      </tbody></table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <br /></td></tr>

  <tr><td>


  <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody><tr>
      <td bgcolor="F78E1E" nowrap="" width="320">
          <font style="text-transform: Capitalize; font-size:12" color="404040">

                  <b>



                  </b>

          </font>
      </td>

      <td bgcolor="F78E1E" nowrap="">
          <font style="font-size:12;color:5C5C5C">


              <font style="font-size:12"> <a href="#" name="loginlink" onclick="window.open('loading.cfm', 'tempestwiloginwindow', 'height=200,width=325,resizable,scrollbars,status'); document.menuloginform.submit();" onmouseover="this.style.color='blue'; this.style.textDecoration='underline';" onmouseout="this.style.color='5C5C5C'; this.style.textDecoration='none';" style="color:5C5C5C;text-decoration:none;font-size:12;"><nobr>Registered User Login</nobr></a><nobr> |</nobr></font><nobr>
          <font style="font-size:12"><a href="inhouse/defaulthelp.cfm" name="helplink" onmouseover="style.color='blue'; style.textDecoration='underline';" onmouseout="style.color='5C5C5C'; style.textDecoration='none';" style="color:5C5C5C;text-decoration:none;font-size:12;" onclick="var helpWin=window.open(this.href,'helpwindow','height=500,width=500,scrollbars');if(window.focus) {helpWin.focus()};return false;">Help</a> |
                  <font style="font-size:12"><a href="http://www.coquitlam.ca/privacy-policy.aspx" style="color:5C5C5C;text-decoration:none;font-size:12;" onmouseover="this.style.color='blue'; this.style.textDecoration='underline';" onmouseout="this.style.color='5C5C5C'; this.style.textDecoration='none';" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> |</font>

          </font>
      </nobr></font></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>

  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>

  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="1" bordercolor="Black">
  <tbody><tr bgcolor="F78E1E">


      <td bgcolor="80B2D2" nowrap="" valign="top" align="center" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" onclick="document.menuhomeform.submit();">
          <font style="font-size:12">
              <b><a href="#" name="homelink" id="homelink" onclick="document.menuhomeform.submit();" style="color:black;text-decoration:none;font-size:12;"> Welcome </a></b>
          </font>
      </td>


      <form action="menuredirect.cfm" method="post" name="menusearchform"></form>
      <input type="Hidden" name="goto" value="selectsearch" />
      <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_sessionid" value="0769A2DA-5056-AE78-7AD8DE5CC457342D" />
      <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_userid" value="GUEST" />
      <input type="Hidden" name="tempest_wi_layerid" value="WC001-20030620175710" />

      <td bgcolor="F78E1E" nowrap="" valign="top" align="center" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='snow'; this.style.cursor='hand'; searchlink.style.color='blue'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='F78E1E'; searchlink.style.color='393939'" onclick="document.menusearchform.submit();">
          <font style="font-size:12">
              <a href="#" name="searchlink" id="searchlink" onclick="document.menusearchform.submit();" style="color:393939;text-decoration:none;font-size:12;" onmouseover="this.style.color='blue';" onmouseout="this.style.color='393939'"> <nobr>Select Properties </nobr></a><nobr>


          </nobr></font><nobr>
      </nobr></td>




      <td bgcolor="F78E1E" nowrap="" valign="top" align="center" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='snow'; this.style.cursor='hand'; selectionlink.style.color='blue'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='F78E1E'; selectionlink.style.color='393939'" onclick="document.menuselectionlistform.submit();">
          <font style="font-size:12">
              <a href="#" name="selectionlink" id="selectionlink" onclick="document.menuselectionlistform.submit();" style="color:393939;text-decoration:none;font-size:12;" onmouseover="this.style.color='blue';" onmouseout="this.style.color='393939'"> <nobr>View Selected Properties </nobr></a><nobr>
          </nobr></font><nobr>
      </nobr></td>

      <td bgcolor="F78E1E" nowrap="" valign="top" align="center" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='snow'; this.style.cursor='hand'; reportslink.style.color='blue'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='F78E1E'; reportslink.style.color='393939'" onclick="document.menureportsform.submit();">
          <font style="font-size:12">
              <a href="#" name="reportslink" id="reportslink" onclick="document.menureportsform.submit();" style="color:393939;text-decoration:none;font-size:12;" onmouseover="this.style.color='blue';" onmouseout="this.style.color='393939'"> <nobr>View Property Details </nobr></a><nobr>
          </nobr></font><nobr>
      </nobr></td>


      <td bgcolor="F78E1E" valign="middle" align="center" width="100%" height="100%"><font style="font-size:1pt"> </font></td>
  </tr>

  </tbody></table>

  </td></tr>
  </tbody></table>
  </font>

  <br />

  <table width="100%" height="60%">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td align="Left" valign="top"><font face="Arial" size="2"><font size="2" face="TheSansOffice">
  <font size="3" color="#0065A4">Welcome to the City of Coquitlam's Property Inquiry System.</font><br /><br />
  <!--
  <font face ="TheSansOffice" color=blue> Due to server maintenance, you may experience intermittent disruption on Thursday June 11, 2009 between 10 PM and 11 PM. <br>Thank you for your patience.<br><br></font>
  -->
  <!--
  <font face ="TheSansOffice" color=blue> Please note: This website will be unavailable from Tuesday August 25, 2009 from 8:30 pm to 11:30 pm for server maintenance. Thank you for your patience. <br></font>
  -->
  You are now able to view information related to properties located in the city. You can
  <table>
  <tbody><tr><td><li> check property assessments,
  </li><li> view legal property descriptions,
  </li><li> view property tax and utility levies.</li></td></tr></tbody></table><br />
  Select a property using the "Select Properties" tab.<br />
  Select the information you want using the "View Property Details" tab. <br /><br />
  <invalidtag language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  function goSetup() {
      var opts = new String("status,resizable,scrollbars");
      var newwin = window.open("../webinquiry/inhouse/accountreq.cfm", "Coquitlam", opts);
      if (document.all){
      newwin.moveTo(0,0)
      newwin.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height)
      }
      return;
  }
  //-->

  <!--
  If you have an account with us, click "Registered User Login" above to obtain a tax certificate or apply a payment to your Web Customer Account.
  <br> <br>
  If you have any questions on the information provided, please contact us via <a href="mailto:PropertyTaxInquiries@coquitlam.ca">email</a> or call us at 604-927-3050.<br>
  -->
  <!--
  <P>For a Web Customer Account application, please click <a href="#" onclick="goSetup();">Account Request Form</a>. We will contact you as soon as<br> the account has been set up.
  <p>
  -->
  </invalidtag></font></font><p><font face="Arial" size="2"><font size="2" face="TheSansOffice">
  <!--If you are already a customer of BC OnLine, log on to their web site at <a target="BC Online" href="https://www.bconline.gov.bc.ca"> www.bconline.gov.bc.ca</a> and select Tax Certificates Online from the main menu. <br>
  For information about BC OnLine, or to become a customer, see their website or call them at (250)953-8250.
  -->
  If you require a <font size="3" color="#0065A4">Property Tax Certificate</font> please visit one of the websites noted below:
  <br /><br />
  •       Visit <a href="http://www.ltsa.ca">myLTSA Enterprise</a> for more information about myLTSA and becoming a customer. If you already have an account, log in and from the main menu, select Service Providers and Order Tax Certificates.
  <br />
  •       Visit <a href="http://www.bconline.gov.bc.ca">BC Online</a> for more information about BC Online and becoming a customer. If you are already a customer of BC Online, log in and select Tax Certificates Online from the main menu.
  <br />
  •       Visit <a href="http://www.apicanada.com">APIC</a> if you prefer to pay for the tax certificate by credit card, open an account and order your Tax Certificate.

  </font></font></p></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>

  <br />


  <table width="100%">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td valign="top">

  <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="F78E1E">
  <tbody><tr>
      <td>

              <font face="arial" size="2" color="404040">

                              <a href="http://www.coquitlam.ca/city-services/taxes-utilities/property-taxes.aspx" style="text-decoration:underline" target="_blank">Coquitlam Property Taxes &amp; Assessment</a>

                           | 

                              <a href="http://www.bcassessment.bc.ca/" style="text-decoration:underline" target="_blank">BC Assessment Authority</a>

                           | 

                              <a href="http://www.sbr.gov.bc.ca/individuals/Property_Taxes/Home_Owner_Grant/hog.htm" style="text-decoration:underline" target="_blank">Homeowner Grant</a>

                           | 

                              <a href="http://www.coquitlam.ca/city-services/taxes-utilities/property-taxes/how-to-pay-your-property-tax-bill.aspx" style="text-decoration:underline" target="_blank">Homeowner Grant</a>


              </font>

      </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>

  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <hr />
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bordercolor="Black">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td align="Left">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" border="0" bordercolor="Black">
          <tbody><tr>
              <td><font size="1" face="TheSansOffice">Copyright © 2001-2018 <a href="http:\\www.tempestdg.com" target="_blank">Tempest Development Inc.</a></font></td>

              <td width="10"> </td>

              <td><font size="1" face="TheSansOffice">Copyright © 2001-2018 <a href="http:\\www.coquitlam.ca" target="_blank">City of Coquitlam</a></font></td>


          </tr>
      </tbody></table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>


  </body></html>
  ```